# How to change Android Studio language

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I installed Android Studio(V 1.0) on my Windows 10 desktop. But the app shows this image: [image: Android Studio] Is this any problem with my computer or this is another language? How can I fix this?

Comment: Why installing v1? Try latest version (3.1), if it persists write back.

Answer (score -1):

Version 1.0? Go ahead and install the current version which is 3.1.

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Btw, it does not look like a different language. Could be a problem with fonts.

Comment: You should definitely try it first. Go for a clean install for version 3.0/3.1